# Ignore file extensions only on my machine

Tags: tortoisesvn

My team lead just added a lot of binary files that shouldn't be in source control.  I have to pick and choose my battles with him and this isn't one I think is worth bringing up, but I'd like to just ignore these files on my machine without affecting everyone elses.  Is this possible?

We're using TortoiseSvn.  I've honestly never used the command line so until I learn how to do that I would prefer a solution using the GUI.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your files resides in a special directory, you could simply use the `Add to ignore list` from the shell-context menu.

From the `settings/general` tab you can also add global ignore patterns, based on extension.

Comment: I wondered about that, but just to make sure I'm clear on this: When I add items to the global ignore list from my computer it only affects my machine... it's doesn't affect everyone elses?

Now that I think about it I suppose it would have to be that way since it's being done on the client side.  Thanks.